# Android Bookmak Page by Clicking Image not working

Tags: android

I wrote the core to add PDF pages to shared-preference for bookmarks, but when I click the image neither the image get changed nor the page number added to the book mark list.

Below is my code. It show me no error and image get clicked but the page number not added to spinner for book mark list.

Before I used a textview for the task and that was working fine but now I want a tag image to get changed when I tag or un-tag a page.

```
   @EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.actionbar)
public class PDFViewActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "myfile.pdf";

    public static final String KEY_BOOKMARKS = "bookmarks_pages";
    @ViewById
    PDFView pdfView;

    @NonConfigurationInstance
    String pdfName = SAMPLE_FILE;


    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Integer pageNumber = 1;

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";

    Spinner bookmarkSp;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    private final int TotalPages = 57;



    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        display(pdfName, false);
    }


    int check = 0;

    private void display(String assetFileName, boolean jumpToFirstPage) {

        if (jumpToFirstPage) pageNumber = 1;



        int x = TotalPages;
        int[] page_seq = new int[TotalPages];
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalPages; i++) {
            page_seq[i] = --x;
            Log.d("testdesp", "" + page_seq[i]);
        }
//       .pages(2,1,0)

        pdfView.fromAsset(assetFileName)
                .defaultPage(TotalPages)
                .pages(page_seq)
                .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total_page)).setText("/ " + pdfView.getPageCount());
                    }
                })
                .onPageChange(this)
                .load();

        findViewById(R.id.btn_go).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.tag_btn).setOnClickListener(this);
        bookmarkSp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_bookmark_list);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String pages = sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "");
        String[] split = pages.split(",");
        list.add("");
        for (String val : split)
            if (val.length() > 0) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(val);
//                value = pdfView.getPageCount() - (value - 1);
                value = TotalPages - (value - 1);
                list.add("" + value);
            }

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        bookmarkSp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (++check > 1) {
                    String val = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (val.length() > 0) {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(val);
                        value = pdfView.getPageCount() - (value - 1);
                        pdfView.jumpTo(value);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        bookmarkSp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_page_number)).setText(pageCount - (pageNumber - 1) + "");
        if (check(page))
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.tagged);
        else
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.untaged);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private boolean displaying(String fileName) {
        return fileName.equals(pdfName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.fade_out));

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_go:
                int page = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_page_number)).getText().toString());
                page = TotalPages - (page - 1);
                pdfView.jumpTo(page);
                break;
            case R.id.tag_btn:
                if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.untaged).getConstantState() ) {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "") + pageNumber + ",").commit();
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.tagged);



                    dataAdapter.add(pdfView.getPageCount() - (pageNumber - 1) + "");
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tagged).getConstantState() ) {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "").replace(pageNumber + ",", "")).commit();
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tag_btn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.untaged);


                    dataAdapter.remove(TotalPages - (pageNumber - 1) + "");
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    boolean check(int page) {
        String number = sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "");
        Log.d("testdisp", pdfView.getPageCount() + "  ** " + number + "   ****" + number.contains(page + ","));
        return number.contains(page + ",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by adding a drawable resource

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tagged" />
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/untaged" />
    </selector>
```

and made below changes in my java activity code.

```
 if (((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_tag)).isChecked()) {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "") + pageNumber + ",").commit();
                    ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_tag)).setChecked(true);


                    dataAdapter.add(pdfView.getPageCount() - (pageNumber - 1) + "");
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else  {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_BOOKMARKS, "").replace(pageNumber + ",", "")).commit();
                    ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_tag)).setChecked(false);
}
```